# How to append a sequence number to a non id field which is String at the time of insersion?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

This might be similar to the sequence generator for id case. But it doesn't solve my current scenario.

Is it possible to append an increment no or count(*)+1 value to a non-id database field at the time of insersion? I am using SQL Server and I am trying to implement a logic that is applicable for a concurrent operation scenario.

I have a table that has a field which stores the code for different products like ESB-GRO-VEG, and each time I add a new item to the product I need to append this code with a sequence no as in ESB-GRO-VEG-001, ESB-GRO-VEG-002, ESB-GRO-VEG-003 etc. I have looked at examples using sequence generator but it can be applied only to id or primary key field. Is there way to implement this? The following is part of my entity code.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="ID")
private Long Id;

@Column(name = "PROD-ID")
private String prod_id;     //------ This is the field I need to append the sequence number.

@Column(name="PROD_TYPE")
private String prod_type;

@Column(name="PROD_QUANTITY")
private BigDecimal quantity;

............. Getter and Setter Methods ..........
```

The sequence no I need to generate doesnt start from integer '1', I need it to follow the 3 digits or more format starting from 001, 002 etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Please please please help me!

Comment: Why can't you do it "prod_id" setter method?

Comment: but how am I going to get the value of id field in setter method? May be I dont understand what you meant. Please explain.